# Erase all photos in a folder but not the last 5 on php

Tags: php

i want to create a php script who erase all the photo in one folder but not the last five of them, i dont know if in php is possible to know the date of creation of a file, i really dont know how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last modified time of a file using [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php). You mentioned the creation date; On a Windows system you can get the creation time using [filectime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) however on a Unix based system this will just get the changed time since Unix systems don't store the creation date of a file.

Once you have this info, a basic technique would be to just loop over each file in the folder grabbing their modification times, then delete all but the ones with the 5 latest times.

A quick example, although there's probably a much more succinct way of doing this,

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/your/folder')) 
{
    $files = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        if (!is_dir($file))
        {
            // You'll want to check the return value here rather than just blindly adding to the array
            $files[$file] = filemtime($file);
        }
    }

    // Now sort by timestamp (just an integer) from oldest to newest
    asort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);

    // Loop over all but the 5 newest files and delete them
    // Only need the array keys (filenames) since we don't care about timestamps now as the array will be in order
    $files = array_keys($files);
    for ($i = 0; $i < (count($files) - 5); $i++)
    {
        // You'll probably want to check the return value of this too
        unlink($files[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I had a similar need of wanting to know with file creation time so I could order them based on upload/creation time:

// Get all image files with a .jpg,.gif and .png extensions

```
$images = glob('images/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

// Sort images by time uploaded/last modified

```
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $images);
```

Hope this helps you somehow or others to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes from PHP manual

> Note: Note: In most Unix filesystems,
>   a file is considered changed when its
>   inode data is changed; that is, when
>   the permissions, owner, group, or
>   other metadata from the inode is
>   updated. See also filemtime() (which
>   is what you want to use when you want
>   to create "Last Modified" footers on
>   web pages) and fileatime().
>
> Note: Note also that in some Unix
>   texts the ctime of a file is referred
>   to as being the creation time of the
>   file. This is wrong. There is no
>   creation time for Unix files in most
>   Unix filesystems.
>
> Note: Note that time resolution may
>   differ from one file system to
>   another.

Since then, i recomment you to name the file with some thing like : "pic-123456789.jpg"
"123456789" stand for the value of time() of creation day, then do a folder scan, get the time, and delete all but not the last 5